# Integrating wxwidgets in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets

I want to make window-base application in c++, I have listen about wxwidgets.

Can any one tell me how can I use wxwidgets library in my application, any link or tutorial which give me direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/wxwidgets.aspx) is a gentle introduction to wxWidgets in a Microsoft environment. Browse the other stackoverflow questions tagged with wxwidgets too.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, in my opinion, to do this is to look at the samples located in your wxwidgets' "samples" directory, which has sample code for basically all of their widgets.

In VS, make sure to change your linker subsystem target by going to project->properties->linker->System and changing subsystem to "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)"

The rest is pretty standard. Include the .h files for the widgets you plan to use.